# Calculating nCr modulo p, a prime

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

I'm trying to compute nCr modulo p, where p is a prime.

One approach I've tried is to compute n! / (r! * (n-r)!) modulo p using multiplicative inverses, but this fails when either r or n - r is greater than or equal to p, since then the factorials are zero modulo p and the inverses don't exist.

What method works in all cases and not just when multiplicative inverses exist?

Comment: "This algorithm will give nCr=0 for every n greater than p, as mod of factorial will become zero. But this is wrong computation. Ex. 14C1 mod 13 = 1 and not 0." how do you get 0 using your algorithm?

Comment: `f[n] * ((InverseEuler(f[r], p) * InverseEuler(f[n-r], p)) % p)) % p`; where `f[n] is (n! %p)` and InverseEuler(a,b) is `((a^(p-2)) % p)`. This would be the discrete formula for nCr using Euler's theorem for modular multiplicative inverse. f[n] for n>=p will be zero, and hence the value of nCr will become zero. Correct me if I am wrong. @IVlad

Comment: That formula only works for `f[x], p` coprime. Multiples of `p` are not coprime with `p`.

Comment: @IVlad oh yes, and this condition fails after that. I missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [Lucas's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem)

```
C(14,1), p=13
N = 14 = 1 * 13 + 1
K = 1  = 0 * 13 + 1
C(N,K) mod p = (C(1,0) mod 13 ) * (C(1,1) mod 13) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculating nCr modulo p,p is prime number

1. pre-calculate the factorial of n modulo p using
   **fact[n]=n*fact[n-1]%p**
2. pre-calculate inverse of factorial of n modulo p, using
   **invfact[n] = modular_inverse(n)*infact[n-1]%p**
   modular_inverse can be easily found out by using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).(As p is prime number both can be used)
3. Get the nCr by multiply **fact[n]*infact[r]*infact[n-r]%p**

Another Method:
You can also use pascal method to calculate nCr

As, for any nCr,you can use

```
row[0]=1;
for(i=1;i<n/2;i++)
{
   row[i]=row[i-1]*(n-i+1)/i
}

for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++)
{
   row[i]=row[n-i]
}
```

In this you have to take modulo_inverse of **(i)** using any of the above way( [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) )

Reference: [Best known algos for calculating nCr % M](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m)